# Excel auto sorting and matching data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to use a formula to find matches and sort columns based on matched data (numbers).  The groups are quite large (32,000 rows) of numbers.

I can sort the data and have a formula tell me if there is a match but I have to sort each column individually and then I have to adjust every cell that doesn't match, by moving them up or down to match adjacent cell.

Is it possible to have a formula sort the data and actually move the cells to match up so the two cells display the same data?  and if there is nothing to match it either just displays a blank or even better, the difference in SUM of the two cells?

[image: sample data]

Comment: Are you willing to write a macro?  Macros are based on VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) and can pretty much be written to do anything with enough effort.

Comment: Have you tried VLOOKUP? =VLOOKUP(B2,A:A,1)  You would need some extra columns, but it will tell you if the value is found or put a #N/A in the box.

Comment: i have tried both but i just don't have enough knowledge to get the macro to work properly and i can't seem to figure out how to get the VLOOKUP to actually sort the data and replace B with the difference between A & C but then i want the formula to insert a space where the data isn't found in C?

Comment: Selection.Insert Shift:=XlDown, CopyOrigin:xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove  that will move a row down, you do have to define a selection first.  VLOOKUP doesn't sort, you have to pre-sort.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro I wrote that kind of does what you want. It already assumes two sorted lists. Modify to fit your columns, delete what you don't need, and possibly add a sort function in the beginning. Enjoy!

```
Sub compareCheckNumbers()
```

' Macro1 Macro

' compare check numbers, then delete if row is matching

```
rowNum = 3
Do
    If (Range("C" & rowNum).Value > Range("L" & rowNum).Value) Then
        'shift down first set
        Range("A" & rowNum & ":G" & rowNum).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ElseIf (Range("C" & rowNum).Value < Range("L" & rowNum).Value) Then
        'else shift down second set
        Range("J" & rowNum & ":P" & rowNum).Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    ElseIf (Range("C" & rowNum).Value = Range("L" & rowNum).Value And Range("D" & rowNum).Value = Range("M" & rowNum).Value And Range("F" & rowNum).Value = Range("O" & rowNum).Value) Then
        'delete outstanding data if matching
        Range("A" & rowNum & ":G" & rowNum).Select
        Selection.ClearContents
    End If
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
Loop While (Range("C" & rowNum).Value <> "")
```

End Sub